# Inline Visualforce Page Dynamic Height

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce, inline, height

I am iterating wrapper list on Visualforce page, I am not sure how many records will be iterate, So is there any way to make inline page height dynamic

Comment: I am using Custom Object

Comment: there is an app in appexchange [Inline VisualForce Expander](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004cEEyEAM).. Prev it worked but after winter 16 release, I don't think it is working now because [REQUIRESCRIPT No Longer Executes JavaScript on Page Load](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_requirescript.htm)

Comment: Yes.. That's the problem after winter 16.

Comment: Yogesh..  just display 10-15 records at a time and go with pagination option..and for dynamic inline vf page height, I don't think that is possible currently

Comment: check this ans if this help or not http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46200/dynamically-resize-visualforce-section-in-page-layout

Comment: I already go through this URL but nothing works :-)