# How to resize VF page

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, visualforce

I did a VF page, to show a message. how can I resize it to fit full component? thank you!
[image]

this is the code I have.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically resize VisualForce section in page layout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46200/dynamically-resize-visualforce-section-in-page-layout)

Comment: thank you Abhishek, I saw this post. But I am new to VF pages, and need some help. I am not sure what exactly I need to add. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, if you mean if you want to apply the style to the whole page:

```
<apex:page >
    <body style="background:red;height:100%;width:100%">
            <div >
                <b> Test</b>
             </div>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: thank you Clairvoyant, but I still get the scrollbar(( and borders((( I am looking for a way to fill whole "component" with the message