# How to resize the visualforce page in the pagelayout

Tags: visualforce, javascript

How to resixe the inline visualforce page in the pagelayout. Is there any ap exchange products or any code that I can do this ?

Comment: Are you talking about VF pages, which you use in standard layout? There is an option for height and width.

Comment: Also [vote here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpiMAAS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the size of visual-force page from the page layout but it will be static height and will not change according to the content of the VF page(You can enable scroll bars as well).

For setting the height, click on the wrench icon you see on the VF page block in the standard page layout editor and set the height in pixels.

If you want the height to change based on the content, you will run in cross domain issues as VF pages and Standard layouts are served from different domain. However if you still want to go into it, you may have a look at this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24958/automatically-resize-inline-visualforce-components-on-standard-pagelayout/66057#66057).

Comment: Eh, used to be possible via Post Messaging but they disabled sidebar hacks so you can no longer add a listener to the parent window.